# Xcode 8.3.3 won't accept AppIcon

Tags: ios, xcode

When i try to drop PNG images for AppIcon in Assets.xcassets,
Placeholder: iPhoneApp iOS 7-10 60pt

Xcode does not accept these images. Images are PNG of right size 120x120(60x60@2x) and 180x180(60x60@3x), respectively.

If you have any suggestion please help.

[image: Problematic AppIcon placeholder]

Comment: remember the images that go here HAVE to be png or jpg

Comment: so don't get fooled by the Tiff format you are forced to use when doing for example a screenshoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this.

Problem was that my files, although PNG images, did not have .png extension in file name. XCode did not recognize image format without extension, and did not show any warning.
After adding extension, everything start working properly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, three parameters are important for the App Icon:

1. Format: all icon images must be in PNG format. Icon images may include an alpha channel but should not include any transparent regions.
2. The size: Here the base size is 60*60, so 120*120@2x and 180*180@3x.
3. Color model: It should be RGB.

You can check all these values with the Preview Inspector. In your case, the background of your icon is not visible in your screenshot (white or transparent?) so I would check for the transparency.

Also, I would double check the size. Some image editors tend to round the values and add 1px on one of the dimensions.

Comment: I checked format, size and color model many times. Cant see anything strange.